# Convert double array from json to jaxb object

Tags: java, json, jaxb

I'm trying convert double array from json to jaxb object, but I get error. I'm trying different variants.

Example JSON

```
"data": [
            [5426, 0, 5805, 0, 6144, 0, 6496, 0, 6885, 0, 7462, 0, 8023, 0, 8603, 0, 9239, 0, 10412, 0, 11630, 0, 11629, 0, 97754, 0],
            [37443, 0, 40597, 0, 42536, 0, 44193, 0, 45839, 0, 47422, 0, 48826, 0, 50163, 0, 51376, 0, 52232, 0, 52858, 0, 52853, 0, 566338, 0]
        ]
```

---

**This variant return error**
Method threw 'java.lang.NullPointerException' exception.

Example java code

```
@XmlElement(name = "data")
private int[][] data;

public int[][] getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(int[][]  data) {
    this.data = data;
}
```

---

[**This variant return empty**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u48Ws.png)

```
@XmlElement(name = "data")
private List<List<Integer>> data;

public List<List<Integer>> getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(List<List<Integer>>  data) {
    this.data = data;
}
```

Comment: Can you add a main function in order to allow us to test ?

Comment: How do you convert your JSON to Java Object ?

Comment: JAXB is for xml , you should go for json lib mapper like gson, jackson etc.

Comment: @jeanr  I don't know, where I can share example for you

Comment: @atiqkhaled I know, but I have to use jaxb.

Comment: You have two conversion to do here JSON -> Java Object and then Java Object -> XML

Comment: @jeanr  [example](https://github.com/LexaDel/JsonToObjectJAXB)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is bug :(
It hasn't been solved yet.

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=389815